# Crystal report fails to load when application is deployed in IIS

Tags: crystal-reports

I  copied the packageTmp over to the inetpub/wwwroot, then added a website and included it as my path.

Installed the crystal report runtime, CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_4 - but still did not work.

I also have crystalreportviewers13 folder in wwwroot/aspnet _client/systemweb/4_0_30319

This is the error I encountered when I go to the page with crystal report.  May i know where the path is defined? This problem occurs when I deploy my application in IIS.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name.

**Source Error:**

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.  Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

**Stack Trace:**

`[COMException (0x800001fb): Invalid file name.]
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +95
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +270
[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +333
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +877
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +1183
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport() +113
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) +53
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable dataTable)`
....

This is the .cs code behind the .aspx code,for reportxx.rpt

```
m_reportxx = new reportxx();
CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;

DataTable dt = data.GetReport();

reportxx.SetDataSource(dt);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = m_reportxx;
```

I tried this and it worked while debugging in the visual studio environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. but For anyone still looking for the answer:

You need to register crystal reports in page markup

```
<% @ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

Set the property **'Copy to Output Directory'** of the report to **'Copy always'**

the path of the file in the crystalreportsource will be ~/bin/YOURFOLDER/YOURFILE

```
<CR: CrystalReportSource ID ="CrystalReportSource1" runat ="server">
            <Report FileName="~/bin/oilmovement/rptOMDayEnd.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR: CrystalReportSource>
```

Now the report should work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found by 2 days the error and not see nothing wrong...Finally I used **Procmon.exe** (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to trace the error. 
I Filter by **Result** + **is not** + **SUCCESS**, I tried to run again the web application and appear the Error: **ACCESS DENIED** to Folder **X**.
I give the right permission to X folder and works fine.