# Crystal report fails to load when application is deployed in IIS in ASP.net Mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I get a error when after I published the app. Even on the same computer that I devolved on. While developing everything worked fine.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The system cannot find the path specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified.
]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +126
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +315

[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +503
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +1495
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) +99
   ProductionTracker.Web.Reports.CrystalReportGenerator.GenerateReportInPDF(DataTable tb, String reportName) in C:\Users\barry\source\repos\ProductionTracker.Web\ProductionTracker.Web\Reports\Controller\CrystalReportGenerator.cs:37
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602748/10852981 and I cant figure out where to add this in my mvc app.
I checked the permissions on the files and allowed to everyone.
I included the .rpt file in project.
Im not sure what else i should do.

This is the code I have for downloading the file

```
public static void GenerateReportInPDF(DataTable tb, string reportName)
        {
            using (var reportDocument = new ReportDocument())
            {
                var reportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "Reports//" +  reportName;
                reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
                reportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(tb);             

       reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Response, false, reportName);
                reportDocument.Close();
            }
        }
```

This line `ProductionTracker.Web.Reports.CrystalReportGenerator.GenerateReportInPDF(DataTable tb, String reportName) in C:\Users\barry\source\repos\ProductionTracker.Web\ProductionTracker.Web\Reports\Controller\CrystalReportGenerator.cs:37`
looks wrong because its from my development repo. But im not sure what to do about it.

Comment: 1)  The error you are getting and the error you referenced in the other SO post are not the same error.  2)  Are you 100% sure that the `reportPath` variable is returning the path that you think it should be and its the correct path to the report file?  Are you 100% sure the report file is being deployed as part of the project (as in, you can physically see the file on your web server and its path is correct)?

Comment: Thanks that was the issue! I realized that once you save to output it saves it in the bin folder. So i added `/bin` then it worked

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!  btw - you can mark your own answer as correct (I think after some period of time).  That way the question is marked closed :)

Comment: Thanks i marked it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The reason i had the error was because it was saving it to the bin folder once published. So i needed to change the path accordingly. I added `/bin/` to
`var reportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "Reports//" +  reportName;`
Like this
var reportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/") + "Reports//" +  reportName;
Then it worked!